# 2-line quotes on aerodynamics or air

Tags: vedas

I am writing my thesis on aerodynamics for aircraft and as a opening quotes I am planning to mention about aerodynamics in vedic.

Is there any good vedic 2-line quote which glorifies air, aircraft or aerodynamics?

Comment: You can try quoting [Vaimānika_Shāstra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaim%C4%81nika_Sh%C4%81stra) :)

Comment: This chapter of ValmikiRamayana describes Pushpaka Vimana... http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/sundara/sarga8/sundara_8_frame.htm

Comment: @ABcDexter Vaimanika Sastra was written recently.It is not from Vedas or ancient Script.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Yes, i knew this book about aerodynamics and science related to it, that is why i didn't write this as answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Here are some, you can pick whichever you like most.

---

The Shantipath of the Taittiriya Upanishad declares this:

> Namaste Vayo, tvam eva pratyaksham Brahmasi.
>
> ‘O, Vayu, you are the directly perceivable Brahman.’

https://vedanet.com/2012/06/13/vayu-rahasya-the-secret-of-vayu/

---

The following is part of Vayu Stuti by Madhavacharya:

> Vayudeva, You are the life giving force, whose kingdom extends in the
>   entire earthly world, the planets and the heaven (Swarga). You who
>   given birth to these kingdoms, sustained and ruled them and have the
>   ability to destroy them as well with yourself being indestructible. We
>   plead with you to destroy the charlatans and lead us to moksha.

https://dvaitavedanta.files.wordpress.com/2008/04/ocr_vayustuti1.pdf

---

Some of the hymns on Vayu found in the Rig-Veda:

> Drive thy horses, Vayu, come to us with love, come well-inclined and
>   loving us.
>
> O Vayu, with your splendid bounty come

http://www.hinduwebsite.com/sacredscripts/hinduism/rigveda/vayu_1.asp